# setting an input control's Filelist to a previously selected Filelist

Tags: javascript, html, input, filelist

In my web app, the user selects local images via input type='file'. The app has multiple 'brushes' and, for each brush, the user can select a different set of local images to be used as 'paint' by the brush. If possible, I would like to use just one input type='file' and, when a given brush X is the editable brush (only one brush at a time is editable), I'd like to refresh the input so that its Filelist is the editable brush's Filelist, not simply the most recently selected bunch of files. I expect this is not possible. Is that right?

Comment: Can you define "*the editable brush's Filelist*"? Like you're wanting to restrict the folder in which a person can upload a file from?

Comment: Each brush may have a different Filelist. The input will be used to generate several different Filelists; one for each brush. Suppose brush x is currently the editable brush (only one brush at a time is editable). Suppose the user selects Filelist X. Then the user makes brush y the editable brush and selects Filelist Y. Then the user makes x the editable brush. I would like to be able to set the input's filelist to X. The question is whether that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to set the FileList on an input control programmatically as that would imply that you could read (or re-upload) files that the user had not just selected manually (security risk.)

Maybe what you could do instead is compromise on the *"I would like to use just one input type='file'"* part. You could have an array of the input type='file' elements, and then  show/hide them depending on which brush is selected. That would give the illusion of showing a different list of selected files in the UI.

Comment: Thanks, Jordan. Yes, I expect this is what I will have to do.

Comment: However, I would think that I *should* be able to set the input to a previously, validly selected filelist. I'm not asking to read files that the user has not selected manually. The baby always seems to get thrown out with the bathwater in these sorts of issues. Even scenarios that are not risky get banned.

Comment: @JimAndrews I don't know the File/FileList API in depth, but maybe there would be a *temporal* security risk in allowing what you're suggesting. By selecting some files, the user is saying "I grant your web app permission to read the contents of these files *right now*." If the files change in the future, the web app shouldn't have the right to see their new contents. Allowing you to set the FileList of an input element would imply that you can trigger a re-upload; but since you can't re-upload, why bother setting the FileList? It sounds like it's only to make the list visible.

Comment: @JimAndrews ... So maybe it's not so much an actual security risk to allow it, but a perceived risk, and the risk that programmers would think the API is letting them do something (re-upload the same files) that they can't actually do.

Comment: I don't even want to upload the files, never mind re-upload them, by the way. But the way that 'security risks' are dealt with in web tech, we end up with crippled controls that favor app dev over web app dev, and the restrictions go beyond legitimate risk into banning innocent but very useful functionality.

Comment: Once a trust has been established with a site or better a PWA (Progressive Web App) this limitation should be removed otherwise it creates a big annoyance to the user to have to travel folders to save or reload a file of bookmarks for example.  I agree 100% with @JimAndrews

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, since being able to set the default directory is a security risk. You wouldn't want a website to access your file system.